# How to identify date of 6 complete months ago

Tags: java, date

I need to identify the date which is 6 complete months ago. For example:

```
Feb-27, 2012(Today) - It is Feb and we don't count incomplete month, false
Feb-01, 2012 - Still Feb so don't count too, false
Jan-01, 2011 - Completed, false
Dec-01, 2011 - Completed, false
Nov-01, 2011 - Completed, false
Oct-01, 2011 - Completed, false
Sep-01, 2011 - Completed, false
Aug-01, 2011 - Completed, false
Jul-01, 2011 - Already pass 6 complete months, true
```

It should work in whatever date in the future.

I thought of current date minus 30*6=180 days, but it is not accurate.

It needs to be accurate because, for example, if we identify Jul 2011 is valid then *we will housekeep all the data for that month*.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything that probably did not work? Did you try Joda time?

Comment: I don't know about joda time so I am not sure if there are any useful class to solve this.

Comment: Joda time is relatively superior library for date-time than Java's Date. You could see how I have solved the issue for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you could use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/overview-summary.html), here is code for ±6 months calculation:

```
    import org.joda.time.DateTime;
    import org.joda.time.Months;
    ....
    ....
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    DateTime then = new DateTime().withDate(2011, 8, 1);
    if(Math.abs(Months.monthsBetween(now, then).getMonths()) > 6){
        System.out.println("6 mo apart!");
        //your logic goes here
    }
```

Comment: I wonder what "monthsBetween" are doing. I used today and 2011-8-01 to evaluate and it said they are 6 months apart. It is not true. There are only 5 complete months apart.

Answer (score 25):

I would try this simple logic to do the job.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  //Get current date/month i.e 27 Feb, 2012
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6);   //Go to date, 6 months ago 27 July, 2011
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //set date, to make it 1 July, 2011
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thumb up for standard java solution without jodas etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use a library like [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for your time and date needs. Offhand I think you could do this with:

[new LocalDate()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#LocalDate%28%29).[minusMonths(7)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#minusMonths%28int%29).[withDayOfMonth(1)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#withDayOfMonth%28int%29)

(7 months to cover any partial months... leaves an edge case of the first of the month... but eh :) )

Answer (score 1):

## `YearMonth`

The `java.time.YearMonth` class built into Java makes this task simple.

Get the current year-month. This requires a time zone as at any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone. On the first/last day of the month, the month can vary around the world by zone.

```
YearMonth ymCurrent = YearMonth.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )  );
```

We know the current month is incomplete by definition. So move to the previous month.

```
YearMonth ymPrevious = ymCurrent.minusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

Move a further six months earlier if desired.

```
YearMonth ymSixMonthsMore = ymPrevious.minusMonths( 6 );
```

That `YearMonth` object itself may be useful in your code. You can pas these objects of this class around your code.

If you need the first day of a month, ask.

```
LocalDate ld = ymSixMonthsMore.atDay( 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to have a utility which will determine **whether a variable date is 6 months before the reference date** that you will set. Take a look at my code snippet for this problem. It just gets use of `java.util.Calendar`, you don't have to use some other libraries.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(2012, 2, 27);
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal2.set(2011, 8, 1);
        boolean valid = isSixMonthsAgo(cal1, cal2);
        System.out.println(valid);
    }

    public static boolean isSixMonthsAgo(Calendar referenceDate, Calendar dateToBeTested) 
    {
        int year1 = referenceDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month1 = referenceDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        int year2 = dateToBeTested.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month2 = dateToBeTested.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        if ((year1 * 12 + month1) - (year2 * 12 + month2) > 6)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```